# Blurry Text On Model After Render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, uv, eevee-render-engine

I'm UV mapping some text  which I did in Illustrator and exported PNG 300 resolution. And I rendered it using cycles and EEVEE. Cycles render gives a more crisp image of the text, while EEVEE seems blurry. I prefer to use EEVEE, becauce my PC is old and takes a while to render. Is there a way my text can look more sharp/crisp usin EEVEE.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: is Depth of Field on?

Comment: I have turned that off. It's only with EEVEE render it's blurry.