# Image Is Blurry When Using Glass Node In Cycles

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I'm rendering my model in cycles render, and I have added a glass node on the screen (separate object) in front  where the text is, I'm doing an orthographic view render. But the result I'm getting is somewhat terrible. The image from behind is just blurry.

[image]

Comment: Hi. Please make the title of your question specific to the problem you are having and not just the general topic. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you used a solid glass ball instead of a hollow sphere as a real life front glass.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Blurry Text On Model After Render](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/186773/blurry-text-on-model-after-render)

Comment: Please don't post the same question more than once. See [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)

Comment: These a totally different questions. One has to do with the blurry text using EEVEE render and Cycles render. 

And the other question is with blurry glass which has to do with glass node set up rendered in cycles.